# Using spacy's Matcher without a model

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to use spaCy's Matcher class on a new language (Hebrew) for which spaCy does not yet have a working model.

I found a working tokenizer + POS tagger (from Stanford NLP), yet I would prefer spaCy as its Matcher can help me do some rule-based NER.

Can the rule-based Matcher be fed with POS-tagged text instead of the standard NLP pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the words and tags for a spacy document from another source by hand and then use the Matcher. Here's an example using English words/tags just to demonstrate:

```
from spacy.lang.he import Hebrew
from spacy.tokens import Doc
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

words = ["my", "words"]
tags = ["PRP$", "NNS"]

nlp = Hebrew()
doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=words)
for i in range(len(doc)):
    doc[i].tag_ = tags[i]

# This is normally set by the tagger. The Matcher validates that
# the Doc has been tagged when you use the `"TAG"` attribute.
doc.is_tagged = True

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{"TAG": "PRP$"}]
matcher.add("poss", None, pattern)
print(matcher(doc))
# [(440, 0, 1)]
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the big help on this. This really help to understand how to use the matcher. Thumbs up!

Comment: Works like a charm!! Now just left to understand what's 440 ? :-)

Comment: 440 is the internal representation for the match ID `"poss"`. You can see the corresponding string with `nlp.vocab.strings[440]`. (Look at the examples in the docs: https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching.)

Comment: Yup. got that. Thank! The thing that I try to understand now, is that if I can do dependency parsing based on spacy's dependency parsing, or "inject" mine.

Answer (score 1):

Sincy I am using stanfordnlp - there seem to be a gap closer :-)

https://github.com/explosion/spacy-stanfordnlp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to train a new statistical model with spaCy, you should read the documentation on [Training spaCy’s Statistical Models](https://spacy.io/usage/training).

Comment: That would be too much work :) ... Did consider that though. But a gut feeling tells me that ... if no one more equipped for the job did that before me. I am not going to be the one to create the new Spacy Hebrew model.... PLUS: I only want a rule based NER anyway, as it will be much more simple / effective. Again... gut feeling + some experiments with existing Hebrew NER services.

Comment: Fair enough - but if you can't make a new model and one doesn't already exist, then you're pretty much out of luck with spaCy. This answer might help you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48590848/2755793

Comment: Yupp... tough life.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, spaCy does not have a trained model for Hebrew yet. For you to use languages without models,

```
from spacy.lang.he import Hebrew
nlp = Hebrew()
#or
nlp = spacy.blank("he")
```

Pretty sure you can build you rule-based matcher from here.

Comment: Sounds promising. Will it allow me setting tokens as an external input?